# Duplicate jar entry-android

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I added 3rd party .aar file to my app. its runs smoothly without any issue. But when going to create APK file i get duplicate entry error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForQaRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Volumes/***/**/PROJECT/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/qa/release/0.jar] (Can't read [/Users/ayeshdon/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/934a6f302e2712d6028d37a9dc4ccd20/jars/libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate jar entry [org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils$1.class]))
```

My Gradle file is like this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
implementation (project(":LIBRARYNAME"))
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever that "3rd party .aar file" may be, it complains about some `Duplicate jar entry [org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils$1.class]`; therefore it's either:

```
implementation (project(":LIBRARYNAME")) {
    exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-lang3"
}
```

Or:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar", "*.jar"]) {
    exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-lang3"
}
```

Comment: the question is rather insufficient, because `:LIBRARYNAME` is missing altogether. it might be required to exclude it there.

Comment: it was local library built for local bank in sri lanka, name is LCTrustedSDK